# creating an image inside a setInterval not starting with the same position

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ybyu5/4/

```
function CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg() {
            var nh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 267) + 1);

            var enemy = document.createElement('img');
            enemy.src = 'enemy.jpg';
            enemy.className = 'Enemy';
            enemy.style.top = nh + 'px';
            // enemy.style.left = '270px';
            //enemy.style.right = '0px';
            pane.append(enemy);
            enemy.onload = function () {


                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.Enemy').animate({ 'left': '-=20px' });
                }, 200);
                //alert(enemy.style.right);
            }
        }
```

i want when every image is created it should have the right set to 0 px and when it reach the border on the left it should disappear anyway to do this ?

Comment: .animate() uses jQuery's unique animation interval so you don't have to handle it. Either change .animate() to .css() or remove the interval.

Comment: that was not my question

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Sora, see http://jsfiddle.net/ybyu5/10/, it's just what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` for container:

```
.Container
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: White;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybyu5/5/)

[Updated fiddle with deleting hided dom elements.](http://jsfiddle.net/ybyu5/10)